# Find orthogonal complement- complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

> Let $W=sp([i, 2-i, 1+3i)]$, find the orthogonal complement of W.

I am looking at the correct solution of:

$$sp([1+2i, 1, 0], [-3+i, 0, 1])$$

How is that obtained?

My approach would be to set $i+(2-i)+(1+3i)=0$, then it follows that $i=-(2-i)-(1+3i)$. But going from here I am a little lost.

Comment: you should assume $ia+(2-i)b+(1+3i)c=0$, then solve it.

Comment: Right but that's gives ia = -2+i when b=1 c=0, and ia = -1-3i when b=0 c=1. Which disagrees with the solution. I m not sure what I m missing here.

Comment: The subspace is unique, but the spanning vectors are not.

Comment: Why did you set that quantity to zero????

Comment: @copper.hat what am i supposed to set it to?